# Is it normal for MacBook Pro to get extremely hot under idle loads?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro and this is about the first Mac I've worked with. The metal case above the keyboard gets extremely hot even when I'm not using the MacBook but have it on. Under normal and high loads that part of the case gets hot enough to burn if touched for about a second.

I can't tell if this is normal considering it doesn't seem to have a fan or a fan moving fast enough to be audible. I am almost wondering if it's intended and the Metal case is used to dissipate heat.

Comment: No that doesn't seem normal to me. That happened when Xcode builds something or iMovie is at work. You can use some temperature readers or activity monitor to see what can be the problem. If it isn't any app, fan seems stuck.

Comment: [retina macbook pro running very hot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155439/retina-macbook-pro-running-very-hot?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah. It looks like it is a duplicate, everything I was finding before was in regards to the laptop under heavy loads which is much different than under light loads or idle

Comment: I should also note that my MacBook is now experiencing intermittent display issues where parts of the screen (either the laptop display or my secondary dell monitor) has part of the screen turn black for a frame.  So this heat issue likely isn't normal.

Comment: Did you run any temperature monitoring app? You can get it reopened by explaining how it is different, but before that, bring in some data.